# xpath and id is not working of a particular page of mobile app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium, simulator

I am trying to automate a mobile app.I am using appium java.While automating,xpath and id of a particular screen is not working.All the screens are working fine but it stucks on a particular page in which none of the id and xpath are working.Deals section are not working.
No error are shown.
here is the code

```
package tests;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class BaseClass {
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver ;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        try {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "SM MO15G");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "R9ZNA0374XT");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.0");
        //cap.setCapability("ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError", "true");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.tringapps.everest.marketplace");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.everest.MainActivity");
        //cap.setCapability("appWaitForLaunch", "false");
        cap.setCapability("automationName" ,"uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability("skipuUnlock", "false");
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        MobileElement skip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"next_button_onboarding\"]"));
        skip.click();
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        MobileElement skipcaliber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"skip_button_onboarding\"]"));
        skipcaliber.click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
        MobileElement deals = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc=\"home-dealOfTheDay-seeMore\"]"));
        deals.click();
        
        
        }
        catch(Exception exp) {
        System.out.println("cause is :" +exp.getCause());
        System.out.println("Message is :" + exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        System.out.println("I am inside the sample test");
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please include a screenshot of this part of your app and also the hierarchy

Comment: You can use uiautomatiorviewer(only android) to see the real xpath and id of the relevant page. Do you have a pageSource for that page?